# TextView highlighting text doubts

Tags: iphone

I am doing a bible application ,i have completed the displaying of verses in textview.I became struck when i tap a verse i shouldn't highlighted.I didn't know how to do this.I provide a image url to show that i want exactly like this.
Thanks in advance

[image: .image]

Comment: Is there any ios bible application sourece code avilable for reference?

Answer (score 1):

Text View Has some property by double presssing on the text view we can get the highlited lines as u asked this was the sample code below

.h file

```
{
    UITextView *textView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *text
```

.m file

```
-(void)setupTextView
{
   self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
   self.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18];
   self.textView.delegate = self;
   self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   self.textView.text = @"Hello this is about the text view, the difference in text view and the text field is that you can display large data or paragraph in text view but in text field you cant.";
   self.textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
   self.textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
    self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    // this will cause automatic vertical resize when the table is resized
    self.textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    // note: for UITextView, if you don't like autocompletion while typing use:
    // myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [self.view addSubview: self.textView];  
}
```

call the method in viewdidload

Comment: but i want the highlighted color as yello or orange,and also i have a huge amount of text values in textview,when the user select a verse it highlight that verse olnly